# Error component css applying to main component, and not redirecting properly

Tags: reactjs

I have a Blog.js react component, where I'm trying to make a 404 error page

```
      <Switch>
     <Route path="/new-post" exact  component={UploadImg} />
     <Route path="/" exact component={Posts} />
     <Route path="/:id" exact component={FullPosts} />
     <Route component={Error} />
     </Switch>
```

here are my routes, first of all, the CSS for my error component applies to this component, and I'm not sure why. Second of all, it does not render the error component, when it does not find a matching path why is this?

I believe that it should render, whenever it can not find a valid id, in the route that renders the FullPosts component? What have i misunderstood